# Charts, HorizontalBarChartView, how set values alignment = Center?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, bar-chart

Swift 3.1, Charts, Multiple cells in `tableView` with `HorizontalBarChartView`. 
Is it possible to align the value - centered?
[image]

**Setup charts data:**.

```
   func refreshData() {

    guard let item = self.item, !item.tasks.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    self.titleName.text = item.name
    self.leftNameMargin.constant = CGFloat(30 * item.level)
    self.titleName.textColor = UIColor(hexString: item.color)

    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)

    var colors:  [UIColor] = []
    var yValues: [Double]  = []
    var count = 0.0

    for task in item.tasks {
        count += Double(task.count)
        yValues.append(Double(task.count))
        colors.append(UIColor(hexString: task.valueColor))
    }

    let suffix = String(format: NSXLocalization.string(forKey: KEY_STR_PERCENT)) //fixes '%' duplication
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.roundingMode = .floor
    formatter.numberStyle = .percent
    formatter.positiveSuffix = suffix
    formatter.negativeSuffix = suffix
    formatter.zeroSymbol = ""

    let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: 0.0, yValues: yValues.map { ($0 / count) })
    let dataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: [dataEntry], label: nil)
    dataSet.colors = colors
    dataSet.valueTextColor = .white
    dataSet.barBorderColor = .black
    dataSet.barBorderWidth = 1.0
    dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true
    dataSet.valueFormatter = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: formatter)

    let data = BarChartData(dataSets: [dataSet])
    data.setValueFont(font)
    data.setDrawValues(true)
    data.highlightEnabled = true

    self.chart.data = data
}
```

I Reviewed all internal methods in the charts, but never found a way to center the y values.

Comment: did you have any success implementing this?

Comment: Yes, I created fileprivate class "ABC...": HorizontalBarChartRenderer {
and 
1. override func drawValues(context: CGContext) {...}
2. override func drawValue(context: CGContext, value: String, xPos: CGFloat, yPos: CGFloat, font: NSUIFont, align: NSTextAlignment, color: NSUIColor) {...}
...
}

self.chart.renderer = "ABC..."